# Get all available timezones

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-dateutil

I'm currently working on an application that is required to support multiple timezones.

For that, I'm using the dateutil library. Now, I need a way to present the user a list of all available timezones the dateutil library supports.

Also, is it advisable to store the tz as strings in the database like "Europe/Berlin"?

Comment: `pytz.all_timezones` gives a list of the timezone names that can be used with [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/). Sometimes timezone conversions with [`dateutil` and `pytz` can produce different results](https://gist.github.com/zed/3838828).

Comment: You may want to consider a map-based timezone picker instead of a list.  [Here's one for JavaScript](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).  If you're not writing a web app, I'm sure somewhere there is a native python control that is similar, but I don't know of one off hand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`dateutil` will use the OS timezone info, but does carry it's own compressed timezone info file too.

You could list the available names from the utility code that loads this data:

```
from dateutil.zoneinfo import get_zonefile_instance
zonenames = list(get_zonefile_instance().zones)
```

You'd need to sort and filter that list a little; there are both abbreviated (3 letter) timezone codes as well as "region/city" entries in this list.

Storing those names in a database is just fine.

Note that this loads all data into memory; if that's not desirable you'd need to load the tar file yourself:

```
import os
import tarfile
import dateutil.zoneinfo

zi_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(dateutil.zoneinfo.__file__))
zonesfile = tarfile.TarFile.open(
    os.path.join(zi_path, dateutil.zoneinfo.ZONEFILENAME))
zonenames = [zn.name for zn in zonesfile.getmembers()
             if not zn.isdir() and zn.name != dateutil.zoneinfo.METADATA_FN]
```

Comment: For dateutil 2.6.0, the TAR file has a different file name: `dateutil-zoneinfo.tar.gz`.

Comment: @KurtPeek: thanks; the code now includes easier-to-access utility code to load this data directly, avoiding the need to  hardcode the filename.

Answer (score 2):

For `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil.zoneinfo import getzoneinfofile_stream, ZoneInfoFile
ZoneInfoFile(getzoneinfofile_stream()).zones.keys()
>>> ['Asia/Ujung_Pandang',
     'America/Porto_Velho',
     'America/La_Paz',
     'America/Caracas',
     'Europe/Malta',
     'Etc/GMT-13',
     'Atlantic/Bermuda',
     ...]
```

`pytz` is a little easier

```
import pytz
pytz.all_timezones
>>> ['Africa/Abidjan',
     'Africa/Accra',
     'Africa/Addis_Ababa',
     'Africa/Algiers',
     'Africa/Asmara',
     'Africa/Asmera',
     'Africa/Bamako',
     'Africa/Bangui',
     'Africa/Banjul',
     'Africa/Bissau',
     'Africa/Blantyre',
     'Africa/Brazzaville',
     ...]
```

Note that `dateutil` prefers to use the operating system to determine timezone info. `pytz` uses its own zone files. While there are probably advantages to each, `pytz` provides more consistency if you don't want to manage time zones at the system level.