# How can I convert datetime to unix timestamp in python

Tags: python, datetime, unix, timestamp

I have one date format "Mon, 15 Jun 2020 22:11:06 PT" I want to convert this format to unix timestamp.

I am using the following code ===>

```
news_date = datetime.strptime(news_date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
news_date = calendar.timegm(news_date.utctimetuple())
```

But gives the following error ===>

```
ValueError: time data 'Mon, 15 Jun 2020 22:11:06 PT' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

How can i solve it and get the unix timestamp from this?

Comment: Your problem is in `strptime`. Try to read the doc of such functions and solve this problem. Then go to next problem. One step at a time (if I remember correctly, in the same module you have also unix time [seconds from epoch)/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*2024 edit:*

- ***general note:*** with Python 3.9+, use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). no need for a 3rd party lib anymore.
- ***dateutil-specific:*** dateutil's parser can be fed with a mapping of abbreviations to IANA time zone names, to parse abbreviations. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62609702/10197418).

---

*2020 answer:*

`%Z` can't parse the time zone abbreviation `PT` - I suggest you skip parsing it and add it "manually" instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil

news_date = "Mon, 15 Jun 2020 22:11:06 PT"

# parse string without the timezone:
news_date = datetime.strptime(news_date[:-3], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

# add the timezone:
news_date = news_date.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Pacific'))

# extract POSIX (seconds since epoch):
news_date_posix = news_date.timestamp()
# 1592284266.0
```

if you have multiple strings with different timezones, you could use a `dict` to map the abbreviations to [time zone names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454186/10197418), e.g.

```
tzmapping = {'PT': 'US/Pacific'}
news_date = "Mon, 15 Jun 2020 22:11:06 PT"
# get appropriate timezone from string, according to tzmapping:
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz(tzmapping[news_date.split(' ')[-1]])
# parse string and add timezone:
news_date_datetime = datetime.strptime(news_date[:-3], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
news_date_datetime = news_date_datetime.replace(tzinfo=tz)
```