# Datetime with timezone in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have a string "Fri, 26 Jun 2020 20:47:07 BST". I need to convert the string to UTC?

Timezone (BST,PST,MST,IST,etc.,) will vary from source. So code should be able to identify the timezone and convert it to UTC always...

Comment: Read http://pytz.sourceforge.net/ for why converting local times to UTC is tricky and also how to do it.  Recommendation is to store UTC and display local instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, 'BST' is an ambiguous abbreviation for a timezone. A convenient way to make it unambiguous is to define a timezone mapping `dict`, which you can supply to `dateutil`'s `parser`:

```
import dateutil

s = "Fri, 26 Jun 2020 20:47:07 BST"

tzmapping = {"BST": dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/London')}

dtobj = dateutil.parser.parse(s, tzinfos=tzmapping)

print(dtobj)
# 2020-06-26 20:47:07+01:00
```

getting UTC is now as trivial as

```
# to UTC:
dtobj_utc = dtobj.astimezone(dateutil.tz.UTC)    
print(dtobj_utc)
# 2020-06-26 19:47:07+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil.tz import *
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# This contains the local timezone 
local = tzlocal()
now = datetime.now()
now = now.replace(tzinfo = local)

# prints a timezone aware datetime
print now
```

Comment: Is that Python 2.7? What do you need pytz for? Why the star-import? Also, the question is not about the local time.